# Capacitor and firestore database CORS Issue on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, vue.js, capacitor

I have a small issue that I'm not sure how to fix!

When I query the Firestore database API via Capacitor in an iOS app, I encounter a CORS error:

> Cross-origin redirection to http://developers.google.com/ denied by
> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Origin capacitor://localhost is
> not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 301

I'm using Firebase v9. What should I do?

Thanks in advance,
Imade

Comment: Dear Emad, you have to add specific configurations to your backend, to handle CORS. CORS has no relation to any other place rather than backend.